# jquery.validate slight issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate here is my problem. Everything validates as expected however if i have 5 fields and all have errors they get there error class, as soon as one is correct the error message remains on the remainder of them however the error class is removed and replaced with the validclass on all the inputs.

.js

```
    $("#commentForm").validate({
                errorElement : "span",
                validClass : "has-success",
                errorClass : "has-error",
                errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo(element.parent("div").next("span"));
                },
                highlight : function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $('div').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
                },
                unhighlight : function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $('div').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
                },
                rules : {
                    emailfield : {
                        required : true,
                        email : true,
                        minlength : 3
                    },
                    namefield : {
                        required : true,
                        minlength : 3
                    },
                    urlfield : {
                        required : true,
                        minlength : 3,
                        url : true
                    }
                }
            });
```

.html

```
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-sm"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
        <input class="form-control input-sm required email" type="text" placeholder="Email address" id="emailfield" name="emailfield">
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>

    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-sm"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i></span>
        <input class="form-control input-sm required" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="namefield" name="namefield">
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
```

Comment: one simple way to overcome this error would be to reset the error messages before validating, ie., you can remove the `errorClass` and add `validClass` in entire dom structure . like this `$.each('div',function () { if(!$(this).hasClass('validClass')) { $(this).removeClass('errorClass').addClass('validClass'); }   });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to target the div parent of the current `element`, so try

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest('div').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest('div').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
},
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/U77uW/)

Comment: Works great, I new the answer had to be simple. Is there a way to keep the help text affected by the validation